# F#: Odd type inference behavior

Tags: f#, types

First off, I have a better method of dealing with this issue so it's not a problem.

However, it is something that I don't understand. Can someone explain this?

When I define the swap function as:

```
namespace Utilities
module Misc

let Swap (left : 'a byref) (right : 'a byref) =
    let temp = left
    left  <- right
    right <- temp
```

I am able to use the Swap function like this just fine.

```
Misc.Swap (&s.[i]) (&s.[j])
```

But when I define the module like:

```
namespace Utilities

type Misc =
    static member Swap (left : 'a byref) (right : 'a byref) =
        let temp = left
        left  <- right
        right <- temp
```

I get the following error on both arguments:

```
This expression has type  'b byref but is here used with type  'a ref
```

How did the type inference for the caller's arguments change by moving the function into a type?

Comment: Thanks for this question; we'll likely change the language spec to disallow using 'byref' curried parameters, since partial application would try to capture a byref and that is no good.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an interaction with the tuple transformation that the F# compiler performs on class methods.

Reflector reports the type of `Misc.Swap` as:

```
public static void Swap<a>(ref a left, ref a right);
```

so we can see here that the compiler has transformed the curried arguments into tupled form.

Defining the method with tupled arguments avoids this problem:

```
type Misc =
    static member Swap(left : 'a byref, right : 'a byref) =
        let temp = left
        left  <- right
        right <- temp    

> let s = Array.init 3 (fun i -> i)
> val s : int array = [|0; 1; 2|]
> Misc.Swap (&s.[2], &s.[0]) 
> s;;
> val s : int array = [|2; 1; 0|]
```

Comment: Then shouldn't I be able to call the original problem type with a tuple arg?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you'd like to be able to call. Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually using first working version. I'm just trying to understand why things don't add up

Comment: To be clear, what Reflector sees does not always matter for what's legal in F#.  F# compiles curried methods down into tupled methods, but stores extra metadata that says the thing is actually curried if viewed from F#.  The point being, just because Reflector sees a tupled method, doesn't mean you can call it with tupled arguments from F#.  (Does that make sense?)

Comment: @Brian: Is there any way to see the F# metadata at present?  Any plans for a Reflector plug-in?  Is the PowerPack reflection library the way to go?